# Python socket example , why this program stuck in recvfrom with UDP?

Tags: python, http, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP client here , so i tried to use `socket.sendto()` and `socket.recvfrom()`
to send and receive messages:

So there is an apache server enabled on my system , bind to port 80:

```
  sock = socket (AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
  sock.sendto ( 'GET /' , ( 127.0.0.1 , '80' ) )
  message , servaddr = sock.recvfrom (255)
```

stuck , but `nc localhost 80` with 'GET/' works

Wasn't python's socket by default non-blocking , why i stuck here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to access an HTTP server over UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`). Use TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) instead. Since TCP is a connection-oriented protocol, consider using `socket.create_connection`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out Tornado: http://www.tornadoweb.org/

It's pretty good once you're used to it.
There's sample code in the source.

Good luck.